# Batch Image Processing for Receipts

Tags: php, image-processing

We've developed an application that we use internally for capturing receipts and expense reports.  The receipt images are saved to the server.

Once saved to the server, I'd like to process the files and check to make sure they've been resized, auto-crop (black space), sharpen, etc. so that the receipt is more easily readable.

The web application is written in PHP and hosted on IIS.  Processing could be handled by PHP, or, more likely, something in Windows that would process new images in batches.

I've done some digging, but not found a lot of off the shelf solutions I can use (free or paid).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick is pretty universal set of image manipulation tools and it's cross-platform, in case you need to run your code on Linux. There is also PHP extension that makes is slightly more convenient to work with ImageMagick.